# How to connect to the Oracle database using the Node Js in windows machine

Tags: node.js, windows, protractor

How to connect to the Oracle database using the Node Js in windows machine ?

The Data Base resides in the another machine.

i tried to install it using the following url [https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/INSTALL.md#instwin]  but eneded with errors.

Please help me on this

below is the error i got.

```
 (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Platforms\x64\PlatformTo
olsets\v140\Toolset.targets(36,5): error MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 8.1 w
as not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK ver
sion in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and select
ing "Retarget solution". [C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\oracledb\build\o
racledb.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `msbuild` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_proces
s.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodej
s\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\oracledb
gyp ERR! node -v v4.6.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "oracledb"
npm ERR! node v4.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! oracledb@1.11.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the oracledb@1.11.0 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the oracledb package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs oracledb
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls oracledb
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm-debug.log
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you require 'oracledb' npm module.

Please have a look at reference below.

https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/entry/introducing_node_oracledb_a_node

Comment: I tried with this but no use.  Getting the gyp ERR! build errors. 
if you knew , please provide me the steps.

Comment: Which version of oracle are you using ?

Comment: I am using the  Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit